# Play Framework 2 suppress compiler warnings

Tags: playframework-2.0

I need to suppress these warnings when I try to run my play app:

```
[info] Compiling 8 Scala sources and 15 Java sources to D:\development\stserver\dashboard\target\scala-2.10\classes...
[error] D:\development\stserver\dashboard\app\ldap\UserAuthentication.java:26: warning: com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
[error] import com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory;
[error]                         ^
[error] D:\development\stserver\dashboard\app\ldap\ReadLdapConfig.java:23: cannot access org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableException
[error] class file for org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableException not found
[error]                 try {
[error]                 ^
[error] Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Duser.timezone=GMT
[error] (compile:compile) javac returned nonzero exit code
[error] application -
```

Sure, I could probably figure out how to write the code without using this library but would prefer not to do so.  I'd much rather figure out how to tell play to stop failing / erroring when it sees a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this same problem. Looks like it is a bug in reporting the root cause of a compilation failure rather than a failure caused by the compilation warning itself. Notice that you have a second issue with your code, an actual compilation error:

D:\development\stserver\dashboard\app\ldap\ReadLdapConfig.java:23: cannot access org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableException

If you clear up that error the issue with the warning should go away.